# How to compress the pictures in feed

Tags: java, android

I created a simple app like twitter [github](https://github.com/dingdangmao123/weibo)

I plan to compress the pictures to avoid oom of Android. I use the `Bitmapfactory.decodeFile` to do it, as you know I need to calculate the inSampleSize. But I get 0 by `getWidth()` or `getHeight()`, So how I can get the size of the `ImageView` in `recyclerview` `adapter`?

Comment: Use glide library https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: can glide avoid the  misplacement of picture because of the reuse of `recyclerview`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  // glide
>     compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
> ```
>
> use bellow code in RecyclerView onBindViewHolder method

```
onBindViewHolder()
{

        if (!(photoPath.isEmpty())) {

                int defaultImagePath = R.drawable.default_thumb;
                int errorImagePath = R.drawable.damaged_image;
                holder.mImageView.setImageResource(defaultImagePath);

                String uri = photoPath;
                loadImageWithGlide(mContext, holder.mImageView, uri, defaultImagePath,
                        errorImagePath);

            }
}

public static void loadImageWithGlide(final Context context, ImageView theImageViewToLoadImage,
                                          String theLoadImagePath, int theDefaultImagePath, int tehErrorImagePath) {
        if (context == null) return;

        //placeHolderUrl=R.drawable.ic_user;
        //errorImageUrl=R.drawable.ic_error;
        Glide.with(context) //passing context
                .load(theLoadImagePath) //passing your url to load image.
                .placeholder(theDefaultImagePath) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                .error(tehErrorImagePath)//in case of any glide exception or not able to download then this image will be appear . if you won't mention this error() then nothing to worry placeHolder image would be remain as it is.
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                //.animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
                //.fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                .into(theImageViewToLoadImage); //pass imageView reference to appear the image.

        /*  Normal way to Load Image with Glide.
                 Glide.with(theCtx)
                .load(theUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) // donot store image in cache
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(theImageView);*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("1024x768.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

Log.e("Original   dimensions", original.getWidth()+" "+original.getHeight());
Log.e("Compressed dimensions", decoded.getWidth()+" "+decoded.getHeight());
```

Maybe you get your bitmap from a resource, in which case the bitmap dimension will depend on the phone screen density

```
Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_1024x768)).getBitmap();
    Log.e("Dimensions", bitmap.getWidth()+" "+bitmap.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the size of the imageView immediately after it got created. So you have to call the post method of that view with a runnable implementation to execute code once image loaded.

```
    imageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your code to load image here
            // Here you wil get the actual width and height of imageView for sure
            // Try to use getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredWidth() if needed
        }
    });
```

You can calculate the sampling according to the view size where you are going to apply the image to.

I have created a project with custom image loader. Here is the bitmap helper class I have written to sample and load images.

> (It works only if the images are in Storage or Resources)

**BitmapLoader**
https://github.com/sujithkanna/MenuCardAnimation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hsalf/menuanim/utils/BitmapHelper.java